# What is this SSH syntax?

Tags: ssh

customer has a kind of proxy system for securing access. The way it access is as bellow from powershell (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2):

```
ssh myAllowedUser[userTarget@xx.xxx.xxx.199]@xx.xxx.xx.198
```

Where is this syntax from? I've tried to replicate this, thinking if it was a ProxyJump, without success

```
-J [user@]host[:port]
             Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a
             TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be specified separated
             by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.

PS C:\Users\xxxx> ssh -J myAllowedUser@xx.xxx.xx.198 userTarget@xx.xxx.xxx.199
myAllowedUser@xx.xxx.xx.198's password:
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I wish, when I understand what is being done, create my ssh config file as this

```
Host SERVER_EXAMPLE
    HostName xx.xxx.xx.199
    User myAllowedUser
    ProxyJump xx.xxx.xx.198 #Just for example here
    ServerAliveInterval 10
```

and then later just:

```
ssh SERVER_EXAMPLE
```

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Comment: Isn't `myAllowedUser[userTarget@xx.xxx.xxx.199]` just a very specific form of login name used to login to `xx.xxx.xx.198`? And seeing this login name, the machine `xx.xxx.xx.198` knows internally where to connect...

Comment: @raj yes, yesterday I noticed that 3 hours later. I'll add answer here with more details. Nonetheless, many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end was just a specific way that password vault use login string. That way bellow works as expected.

```
Host SERVER_EXAMPLE
    HostName xx.xxx.xxx.198
    User myAllowedUser[userTarget@xx.xxx.xxx.199]
    ServerAliveInterval 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the CLI as:

```
myAllowedUser%userTarget%target@xx.xxx.xx.198
```